# Python BeautifulSoup: Excluding other tags in in select statement

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm having trouble with selecting text with BeautifulSoup. I am trying to get text from `<span class= "data">` only, but I keep getting results with other elements as well. For example, the words I want are 'Playstation 3' and 'Game Boy Advance' in the code below, not 'PC' Could you help?

soup:

```
<span class="data">
                  PlayStation 3
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
                  Game Boy Advance
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
                  Dec 8, 2022
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
 <a href="/game/pc">
                   PC
                  </a>
```

P.S. I've tried this below
code:

```
console = soup.select('span.data')
for console in console:
    print(console.get_text(strip = True))
```

output snippet:

```
PlayStation 3
Game Boy Advance
Dec 8, 2022
PC
```

Thanks!

Comment: By what rule do you want to select correct `<span class= "data">` ? Always first two?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I want to select all the information within only ```<span class= "data">```. Not the ones that include other tags like ```<a href= '/game/pc'>```

Comment: But there's also `Dec 8, 2022` inside `<span class= "data">`. Do you want to select that too?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will select all `<span class="data">` which don't have any other tags inside them:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<span class="data">
                  PlayStation 3
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
                  Game Boy Advance
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
                  Dec 8, 2022
                 </span>,
 <span class="data">
 <a href="/game/pc">
                   PC
                  </a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for span in soup.select("span.data:not(:has(*))"):
    print(span.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
PlayStation 3
Game Boy Advance
Dec 8, 2022
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks and so fast too. Hope to keep practicing and be like you one day :) @AndrejKesely